How to bind custom UserControl button click to command to UCs parent viewModel
I have a custom control that contains buttons, labels and textboxes. This user control is being used in another View that has a ViewModel. I want to Bind the click event handler from the custom control to a command in the viewModel.
The code for the View:
    public partial class ViewPage : UserControl
    {
        public ViewPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CustomControl_RestartClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("clicked");

        }
    }
}

The code for the custom user control:
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));



    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }



    public static readonly RoutedEvent RestartClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(nameof(RestartClick), RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CustomControl));

    public event RoutedEventHandler RestartClick
    {
        add { AddHandler(RestartClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(RestartClickEvent, value); }
    }

    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnRestartClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(RestartClickEvent));
    }
}

I have this command in the ViewModel I want to bind it to:
public ICommand RestartCommand { get; private set; }

I want to be able to do somehtign like
<views:CustomControl Title="PS04-04"  RestartClick="{Binding RestartCommand}" />


link to github: https://github.com/MaganaLu/MCP_WPF.git

The target of a Binding like {Binding RestartCommand} would be a dependency property of type ICommand like the Button's Command property.

FYI: Just a suggestion but you might want to name your control something other than CustomControl, if only to avoid the confusion with the well-define WPF concept of "custom control" meaning a control not derived from the UserControl class, that has no associated XAML page, which may be styled, and for which you must define a control template

How do I create it for ICommand instead of RoutedEVent? @Clemens

Like any other dependency property. You already have one named Title of type string. Create another one named Restart of type ICommand. In the UserControl's XAML, bind it to the "restart" Button with <Button ... Command={Binding Restart, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>

Then bind the RestartCommand property like <views:CustomControl Title="PS04-04"  Restart="{Binding RestartCommand}"/>

Please note that I have rolled back your question to the original problem. Please avoid changing the question content in such a significant way that it makes existing answers appear pointless. Consider accepting the answer, then ask a new question if you have another problem.

You need a dependency property that accepts an ICommand.
public static readonly DependencyProperty FooCommandProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FooCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomControl));

public ICommand FooCommand
{
  get => (ICommand)GetValue(FooCommandProperty);
  set => SetValue(FooCommandProperty, value);
}

Then somewhere in your user control (probably in an event handler) you need to Execute that command when something happens.
if(FooCommand != null && FooCommand.CanExecute(fooParameter))
{
  FooCommand.Execute(fooParameter);
}

Once you have all that in place, you just bind your ICommand to the property.

Or just bind FooCommand to a control in the UserControl's XAML.

@Clemens I did this but now its lookign for the command in a differnet view model. I get error "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'RestartCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=65300541)'
" its suppose dot be in another viewmodel

@DuckQuackington You wrote "I have this command in the ViewModel I want to bind it to: public ICommand RestartCommand { get; private set; }" - we have no idea which view model you are talking about, or whether there is more than one view model in the first place. When you write {Binding RestartCommand}, the RestartCommand property is expected in the current DataContext,. i.e. the current view model, whatever that is. You haven't told us.

@Clemens Sorry for not providing enough information. I am using WPF for the first time. I truly appreciate your help. I have updated the question. I have a "MainWindowViewModel" that contains the "MCP06Page" view.

From your explanations and code, I think that the problem is most likely caused by the confusion of Data Contexts at different levels of layout.
At the level of <views:ConveyorControl declaration, you expect an instance of DesignMCP06PageViewModel in the data context. But at runtime, in fact, an instance of MainWindowViewModel comes in the data context, which does not have the RestartCommand property.
Without knowing your task in full, the conditions of its execution, I cannot give an exact answer suitable for your solution. Therefore, I will suggest one of the common approaches used in WPF. If it does not suit you, write in more detail about your task and it will be better if you upload the solution to the GitHub repository and provide a link to it.
Creating a Locator.
This is just a container with properties for various data that need to be used at different levels of layout. Most often, the Locator properties are separate instances of ViewModel. In the simplest case (when the properties are initialized once at application startup, necessarily BEFORE the first call to the locator), there is no need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the locator.
    public class Locator
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel MainVM { get; set; } = new();
        public DesignMCP06PageViewModel MCP06_VM { get; set; } = new();
    }

You declare an instance of the Locator in the App resources.
    <Application.Resources>
        <somens:Locator x:Key="locator"/>

Accessing the locator properties:
<Window x:Class="-------------.MainWindow"
        ----------------------------------
        DataContext="{Binding MainVM, Source={StaticResource locator}}">
    <Grid>

        <views:ConveyorControl x:Name="binding"
                               Title="PS04-04"
                               RestartCommand="{Binding MCP06_VM.RestartCommand,
                                                        Source={StaticResource locator}}"/>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>

P.S. The answer is not relevant, because after additional clarification and viewing the Solution on GitHub, it turned out that switching views occurs using the Prism package. In essence, the author's question boils down to how to use Prism correctly.

Hello @EldHasp Yes, I am consfused on why the data context does not communicate with the "MCP06ViewModel" and instead goes to MainWindowViewModel. I have created the custom UserControl in the components folder.The link to the github is here: https://github.com/MaganaLu/MCP_WPF . Once again I thank you for your help!

@DuckQuackington
I looked at your solution. It turns out that you use Prism and switching pages occurs through the services of this package. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with Prism. I also advise you to immediately indicate information about using Prism in the top of your question. It would be even better if you indicated this in the topic title.

Also keep in mind that "switching views" has nothing to do with the original, already answered question. @Duck please ask a new question if you have some other problem. Avoid chameleon questions. Do not forget to accept the answer to your original question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
